# beginner javascript regarding object functions giving TypeError

Tags: javascript

I want addScore in gradebook Object to append score that is passed in to the scores Array. 
However it is giving me an error.

TypeError: Cannot read property 'testScore' of undefined

```
var students = ["Joseph", "Susan", "William", "Elizabeth"];

var scores = [ [80, 70, 70, 100],
               [85, 80, 90, 90],
               [75, 70, 80, 75],
               [100, 90, 95, 85] ];


var gradebook = {
  joseph:{testScore:scores[0]},
  susan:{testScore:scores[1]},
  william:{testScore:scores[2]},
  elizabeth:{testScore:scores[3]},
  addGrade:function(stu_name,grade) {
    gradebook.stu_name.testScore.push(grade);
  }
};

//test call
gradebook.addGrade("susan",100);
console.log(gradebook.susan.testScore); //should display [85 80 90 90 100]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't use "dot" notation for dynamic property names. But you can use bracket notation:

```
gradebook["joseph"]
// is equivalent to
gradebook.joseph
```

...but the expression in the brackets can be a variable that evaluates to be a string with the name of your property:

```
var p = "joseph";
gradebook[p]
```

So for your `addGrade()` function try this:

```
addGrade:function(stu_name,grade) {
  gradebook[stu_name].testScore.push(grade);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this:

```
var gradebook = {
  joseph:{testScore:scores[0]},
  susan:{testScore:scores[1]},
  william:{testScore:scores[2]},
  elizabeth:{testScore:scores[3]},
  addGrade:function(stu_name,grade) {
    gradebook[stu_name].testScore.push(grade);
  }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

[Here is working demo](http://jsfiddle.net/zaheerahmed/XJ5aE/).

Array indexing works with square brackets so try:

```
gradebook[stu_name].testScore.push(grade);
```